# SSH Port Forwarding for legal filesharing on remote network

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

There is a DC (Direct Connect) server set up at my university for students to use on campus.  All off campus ports are blocked.  I have a linux box on campus that I can ssh to from wherever.  I was hoping I could just forward port 1412 from my local machine to the linux machine, but that doesn't work, and I am out of ideas on how to connect.  (I have permission from the admin to do this as well).  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On your local machine:
`ssh -L 1412:dcserver:1412 user@linuxbox`

Then, on your local machine, open your client and use `localhost:1412` as server.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work...

Comment: you have to change `dcserver` and `linuxbox` with connect address/IP, change the `user` name.

Comment: I used, on my local machine: `ssh -L 1412:<address of the hub>:1412   <my username>@<my linux server's name>`  That is correct, no?  Then I do localhost:1412 as my server, but my DC client (Shakespeer) says that it can't resolve localhost:1412

Comment: perhaps there is a port field in your client, in this case, use `localhost` as server and `1412` as port